# Why is the Witcher 2 unplayable on recommended high settings?

Tags: the-witcher-2, graphics-card

I just got The Witcher 2 today and so far it seems quite enjoyable. The problem is that I haven't been able to play much of it so far due to lag that occurs even on low settings. The game recommends that I play on High, but this simply isn't possible; the game pauses every time I so much as turn Geralt's head. Any idea what's causing this problem and what settings I might need to adjust to get the game working at a normal, mostly lag-free speed?

My graphics card is the NVIDIA GeForce 9600 GT, and I have 4 GBs of RAM on my computer. My graphics driver is beta driver 275.27. [All display specs can be found here](http://pastebin.com/69aUTB6v)(results from running dxdiag).

Comment: As always, one of your steps should be to try running in a lower resolution.

Comment: @Strix Ah, didn't know that! This is actually the first time I've had troubles running a game because of graphics in a fair while.

Comment: @Strix Yeah, running at 1400x900 instead of the full 1920x1080 definitely helped.

Comment: Make sure you uninstall the 3D Vision driver, it is said to cause significant problem.

Comment: This game is probably too stressful for a 9600GT at that resolution, yeah. It's just not quite fast enough a card.

Comment: isnt this a bit too localized?

Comment: @Bora I'm unconvinced. If the game recommends that I play the game on settings my computer simply can't handle, I imagine that could be the case with some other lower-end NVIDIA graphics cards, and so the question is applicable to quite a number of people. Can you explain why you think it's too localized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made the following adjustments:

- Installed the latest beta driver from NVidia's website (version 275.2something)
- Adjusted the screen resolution from 1920x1080 to 1360x768.
- Uninstalled the 3D Vision driver
- Updated to Patch 1.1, which removes all DRM(apparently a cause of slowdown up to 30% on lower-end systems)

The game plays at around ~16 FPS on High settings with occasional bursts of lag when entering new rooms, and plays at a much more enjoyable 28 FPS on Medium.

Comment: Obviously you want to play at 800x600 at Wireframe settings.

Comment: How did 1920x1080 with Low settings work?